Android Cucumber tests are not invoked
I have written BDD tests for Android with Cucumber and Gherkin but when I run the test Class "CucumberTestRunner", it shows that tests 0/0 are done, i.e., it doesn't see the tests I have written.
My codes:
CucumberTestRunner.java
package com.example.bddtestingwithcucumbergherkinespressoselenium.cucumber;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "classpath:features",
        glue = "com.example.bddtestingwithcucumbergherkinespressoselenium.cucumber.steps"
)
public class CucumberTestRunner {

}

ToDoListSteps.java:
package com.example.bddtestingwithcucumbergherkinespressoselenium.cucumber.steps;

import io.cucumber.java.en.And;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;

import static androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.typeText;
import static androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.*;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;

import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers;
import androidx.test.ext.junit.rules.ActivityScenarioRule;

import com.example.bddtestingwithcucumbergherkinespressoselenium.MainActivity;
import com.example.bddtestingwithcucumbergherkinespressoselenium.R;

import org.junit.Rule;

public class ToDoListSteps {

    @Rule
    public ActivityScenarioRule<MainActivity> activityRule = new ActivityScenarioRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @Given("the app is open")
    public void theAppIsOpen() {
        System.out.println("Test is running");
        // Launch the app using Espresso's Intents
        //TODO:  wrong: it executes the app every time. must only check app being open and if NOT open, open it.
        Intent intent = new Intent(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(), MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK); // Ensure a fresh start
        InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().startActivitySync(intent);
    }

    @When("I enter {string} as a task")
    public void iEnterAsATask(String task) {
        onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.task_input)).perform(typeText(task));
    }

    @And("I tap the \"Add\" button")
    public void iTapTheAddButton() {
        onView(withId(R.id.add_button)).perform(click());
    }

    @Then("the task {string} should be displayed in the list")
    public void theTaskShouldBeDisplayedInTheList(String task) {
        onView(withText(task)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }

}

ToDoList.feature:
Feature: To-Do List Functionality

  Scenario: Add a new task
    Given the app is open
    When I enter "Buy groceries" as a task
    And I tap the "Add" button
    Then the task "Buy groceries" should be displayed in the list

  Scenario: Mark a task as complete
    Given the app is open
    And the task "Buy groceries" is in the list
    When I tap the checkbox next to "Buy groceries"
    Then the task "Buy groceries" should be marked as complete

  Scenario: Delete a task
    Given the app is open
    And the task "Buy groceries" is in the list
    When I long-press the task "Buy groceries"
    And I tap the "Delete" button
    Then the task "Buy groceries" should be removed from the list

  Scenario: View empty list
    Given the app is open
    And there are no tasks in the list
    Then the message "No tasks yet!" should be displayed

  Scenario: Clear all completed tasks
    Given the app is open
    And the tasks "Buy groceries" and "Walk the dog" are in the list
    And "Buy groceries" is marked as complete
    When I tap the "Clear Completed" button
    Then the task "Buy groceries" should be removed from the list
    And the task "Walk the dog" should still be in the list

build.gradle.kts (app level):
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.bddtestingwithcucumbergherkinespressoselenium"
    compileSdk = 34

    sourceSets {
        getByName("androidTest") {
            assets.srcDirs(files("$projectDir/src/androidTest/resources"))
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.bddtestingwithcucumbergherkinespressoselenium"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.13.1")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")


    testImplementation ("androidx.test:rules:1.6.1")
    androidTestImplementation ("com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2")


    androidTestImplementation ("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.6.1")
    androidTestImplementation ("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.6.1") // For additional Espresso utilities

    androidTestImplementation ("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.2.1")

    androidTestImplementation ("io.cucumber:cucumber-android:7.14.0")
    // apparently no need to:
    androidTestImplementation ("io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:7.14.0")
    androidTestImplementation ("io.cucumber:cucumber-gherkin:7.14.0")
    androidTestImplementation ("io.cucumber:cucumber-java:7.14.0")
}

And the message I have when I run the CucumberTestRunner class : 0/0 tests

